# JQuery/Ajax accepting True/False from PHP function

Tags: php, codeigniter, jquery, boolean

```
function check_jobref_availability(){
    if ($job_reference_already_exists == 0) { 
        $output = TRUE;
    } else {
        $output = FALSE;
    }
    echo $output;
}
```

**complete function**

```
function check_jobref_availability(){       
    $output = 1;       
    $jobrefference = $this->uri->segment(3); //mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['ptitle']);
    $strSQL = "SELECT count(*) FROM projects where ptitle = '" . $jobrefference . "' and companyid = 1";
    $job_reference_already_exists = get_singlecolumn($strSQL);        

    //if it is zero means. no refrence was found and it is good to go to add the new job reference.
    if ($job_reference_already_exists == 0) { 
        $output = 1; // NOT FOUND SO GO AHED 
    } else {
        $output = 0; // MEANS ALREAYD EXISTS give an alert
    }
    echo $output;
```

}

This is my PHP Code (rest of the code actually queries the DB) and returns 0 or 1. Based on which i need to return true or false.

```
var newjobrefrence = $('#newjobrefrence').val().trim();
$.ajax(
{
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>postproject/check_jobref_availability/" + newjobrefrence,        
    data: {ptitle: newjobrefrence},
    success: function(response){
        if (response.d == "false") {
            jobrefrencealreadyexists = 1;
            alert("Job ref found");

        }else{
           jobrefrencealreadyexists = 0;
           alert("Not found");
        }

    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
    }
});
```

And this is my jquery/ajax call. I am new to jquery/ajax.

All it needs to do is call check_jobref_availability, and based on the return value do an alert.

I have tried different combinations like returning Jason (I am not 100% sure if was doing that correctly either), or returning "True" or "False" and simple true; and false; but I can not see the response in my jquery..

I have got few hair left on my head as I have been pulling them all weekend on this.

Any help would be much appreciated to save my hair style.

Comment: Have you checked the body of the response to your post request? (using firebug or something similar).

Comment: Can you open /postproject/check_jobref_availability/ and see that it echoes something at all? Maybe its routing issue

Comment: Check the response it's much easier... A simple console.log(result) can help too. To me it seem like you are testing "TRUE" == "true", JavaScript is case sensitive

Answer (score 0):

Try this once, and check your `firebug's net panel` for the ajax call's response:

```
function check_jobref_availability(){
if ($job_reference_already_exists == 0) { 
    $output = 1;
} else {
    $output = 0;
}
echo $output;
}

success: function(response){
    if (response == 1) {
        jobrefrencealreadyexists = 1;
        alert("Job ref found");
    }else{
       jobrefrencealreadyexists = 0;
       alert("Not found");
    }

}
```

If it doesnot helps, try hitting this link in your browser directly to see the output of your controller if its `echo(ing)` correct output:

```
base_url()/postproject/check_jobref_availability/[any_job_refrence_here]
```

**Update**

```
var newjobrefrence = $('#newjobrefrence').val().trim();
$.ajax({
    type        : "POST",
    url         : "<?php echo base_url(); ?>postproject/check_jobref_availability/", //removed the uri segment       
    data        : { newjobrefrence : newjobrefrence },
    success     : function(response){
        if (response == "1") {
            jobrefrencealreadyexists = 1;
            alert("Job ref found");

        }else{
           jobrefrencealreadyexists = 0;
           alert("Not found");
        }

    },
    error       : function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
    }
});

function check_jobref_availability(){
    if( $this->input->post(null) ){
        $id = $this->input->post('newjobrefrence'); #fetch from the post array and not the uri segment
        //your query here with $job_reference_already_exists
        /*if ($job_reference_already_exists == 0) { 
            $output = 1;
        } else {
            $output = 0;
        }*/
        echo $job_reference_already_exists;
    }

}
```

Comment: My PHP is returing 0 and 1 based on what I provide as a jobrefrence. But the response always get true.

Any suggestions.

Comment: I meant if do alert("response: " + response); first thing in the success function it always returns me true

Comment: Post your full function `check_jobref_availability()` in your question

Answer (score 0):

```
var $true = false;

$.ajax(
{
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>postproject/check_jobref_availability/" + newjobrefrence,        
    data: {ptitle: newjobrefrence},
    success: function(response){
        if (response.d == "false") {
            jobrefrencealreadyexists = 1;
            alert("Job ref found");
            $true = true;

        }else{
           jobrefrencealreadyexists = 0;
           alert("Not found");
        }

    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
    },
    async: false
});

  if($true) return true;

  return false;
```